# The program compiles but it gives an error when ran

Tags: java, maze

While trying to run this code I run into an error but not while compiling it. At the end of each directional method I call the next method in the order that is supposed to go in. What I am trying to do is make a program that will read a maze from a file and solve it. While solving it I want the program to place a P for the path it took and a V for the places that have already been visited. The program is only allowed to go forward left right then back for every direction. When you go a different direction you will have to still go by these rules except that the way you are facing is now the new forward.

Maze Code:

```
    public static boolean goNorth(){
        boolean success;
        if(maze[startCol][startRow] == maze[finishCol][finishRow]){
        return true;
        }
            if(maze[startCol][startRow - 1] == CLEAR){
                maze[startCol][startRow - 1] = PATH;
                startRow = startRow - 1;
                goNorth();
                if(maze[startCol][startRow - 1] == PATH){
                    maze[startCol][startRow - 1] = VISITED;
                    startRow = startRow - 1;
                    goNorth();
                    if (maze[startCol][startRow - 1] == VISITED){
                        goSouth();
                    }   
                }
            }
        goWest();
        return true;    
    }


    public static boolean goEast(){
        boolean success;
        if(maze[startCol][startRow] == maze[finishCol][finishRow]){
        return true;
        }
            if(maze[startCol + 1][startRow] == CLEAR){
                maze[startCol + 1][startRow] = PATH;
                startCol = startCol + 1;
                goEast();
                if(maze[startCol + 1][startRow] == PATH){
                    maze[startCol + 1][startRow] = VISITED;
                    startCol = startCol + 1;
                    goEast();
                    if(maze[startCol + 1][startRow] == VISITED){
                        goWest();
                    }
                }
            }
        goNorth();
        return false;   
    }


    public static boolean goSouth(){
        boolean success;
        if(maze[startCol][startRow] == maze[finishCol][finishRow]){
            return true;
            }

            if(maze[startCol][startRow + 1] == CLEAR){
                maze[startCol][startRow + 1] = PATH;
                startRow = startRow + 1;
                goSouth();
                if(maze[startCol][startRow + 1] == PATH){
                    maze[startCol][startRow + 1] = VISITED;
                    startRow = startRow + 1;
                    goSouth();
                    if (maze[startCol][startRow + 1] == VISITED){
                        goNorth();
                    }   
                }   
            }
        goEast();
        return false;   
        }

    public static boolean goWest(){
        boolean success;
        if(maze[startCol][startRow] == maze[finishCol][finishRow]){
        return true;
        }
            if(maze[startCol - 1][startRow] == CLEAR){
                maze[startCol - 1][startRow] = PATH;
                startCol = startCol - 1;
                goWest();
                if(maze[startCol - 1][startRow] == PATH){
                    maze[startCol - 1][startRow] = VISITED;
                    startCol = startCol - 1;
                    goWest();
                    if(maze[startCol - 1][startRow] == VISITED){
                        goEast();
                    }
                }   
            }
        goSouth();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Maze.txt:

```
20 7
0 18
6 12
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx x
x     x       xxxx x
x xxxxx xxxxx   xx x
x xxxxx xxxxxxx xx x
x            xx xx x
x xxxxxxxxxx xx    x 
xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx
```

Error:

http://s22.postimg.org/etar0eq1t/Code.png

Comment: This is way too much code. Trim it down to a small program that shows your problem.

Comment: Judging from the error and question, I don't think he knows how.

Comment: Your error screen capture doesn't show the error message, only a portion of a call stack.  My crystal ball says the error is a stack overflow.  It looks like you may have some infinite recursion going on.

Comment: Agreed, he has GoWest calls embedded in GoWest function.  Same in others.  Time to chase the recursion demon away.

Comment: Ok thanks. I am new to programming in java and I don't really have the syntax down yet. If at all possible could you show me where the infinite recursion is?

Comment: that error message isn't very helpful.  if you put `> someFile.txt` at then end of the command you use to compile, you can get all the error information into a file, and then you can copy/paste that

Comment: Each of your goXXX methods call itself and other go-methods. According to the stack trace on the image, you have infinite recursion: goWest, goSouth, goEast, goNorth, and again goWest… So your algorithm does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it.  Your code starts by calling North, which if not clear calls West, which if not clear calls South, then East.  Unfortunately, your East call on not clear then calls North again, which will loop the above and blow your stack.  You need a better termination case for your recursion.

Also, there is no "edge of the map" detection going on here such that it might be possible to exit your maze and trash memory given a bad starting condition.  Imagin your starting position is on the North edge of your maze.  Your first call is to go North, which reads off your array and blows things up.  You need to check against map size in your floodfill, walk the maze calls.

Comment: Ok, that makes a lot of sense. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, while trying to make the termination case better I ran into a problem of where should I put the termination case. I'm a Java and programming novice.

Comment: Just google "Java flood fill code"  I found a ton of easy hits.